# Comparing two images using OpenGL

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, graphics

I'm writing a program which draws some plygons which should imitate input (raster)image. After drawing shapes I need to compare my rendered image with input one and then decide if I achive my goal or not. Currently i'm usuing CIMG library to draw. Whole program runs on CPU. I tried to use SFML which uses OpenGL for drawing - rendering was extreme fast, but copying image from GPU to CPU (to make coamparison with input image) take very long. 
I want to:

- render polygons on GPU
- send input (raster) image to GPU
- compare images on GPU using simple "pixel after pixel" comparison:
  (r1-r2)^2+(g1-g2)^2+(b1-b2)^2
- send result of comparison (one number)
  to CPU

Unfortunatelly I don't know if it (comparing two images) is possible to achive with OpenGL. If it is possible I will learn OpenGL or any other library which allows to do my task very fast.

Comment: You could do it in OpenGL using GPGPU-style programming. In your case, perhaps a fragment shader to compare individual pixel values, and then another shader pass to compute maximum difference. But it doesn't sound like the reasonable solution. It is indeed possible to retrieve a pixel-perfect copy of an image from the GPU to CPU. Your original GPU->CPU copying code must have been wrong. I'd work on fixing it instead of coding the comparison on the GPU side.

Comment: Copying from GPU to CPU works good but I takes very long, I repeat this operation thousands times so it is important for me to speed up this operation.

Comment: I see. It's not too clear what "destroyed everything" means. In such case, you can try the fragment-shader approach.

Comment: BTW, what is the output? A sum of the differences?

Comment: Sorry, you are right - I could write it more clearly. Yes a sum of differences should be output from comparison.

Comment: You can still edit your question to make it clearer :-)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an outline of a possible approach. They're really just tips to get you started.

1. Render your image to a texture (I'll call it `Render`) and copy the original into another texture (I'll call it `Orig`). Disable any texture filtering.
2. Create one fragment shader that will compute the difference. In pseudo-code:

   ```
   vec3 render = texture2D(Render, fragmentPosition.xy);
   vec3 orig = texture2D(Orig, fragmentPosition.xy);
   gl_FragColor.r = (render - orig).dot(render - orig);
   ```

   Run this fragment shader on a quad the size of your image, sending the output into another texture (I'll call it `Difference`). You might need to enable rectangular textures.
3. Create another fragment shader to compute partial sums:

   ```
   float sum = 0;
   for (row = 0; row < imageHeight; ++row) {
     sum += texture2D(Difference, vec2(fragmentPosition.x, row));
   }
   gl_FragColor.r = sum;
   ```

   Run this fragment shader on a quad sized `image_width x 1`, sending the output into another texture (`PartialSum`).
4. Either read back `PartialSum` to the CPU (it's much smaller) and sum it there, or create a single-fragment quad and run a modified summation shader to arrive at one number, than read that back.